# To add category filter in Product grid magento2

Tags: magento2, category, grid, filter

I have tried to add Category column in Product grid admin area.I have added it successfully by below code.

```
<column name="category" class="Chilly\Productsgrid\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Category">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Chilly\Productsgrid\Model\Category\Categorylist</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Categories</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

In *Chilly\Productsgrid\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Category.php*, **prepareDataSource()** method

```
$fieldName = $this->getData('name');
if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
    //$categories=array();
    foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
        $p_id=$item['entity_id'];
        $product=$this->_productloader->create()->load($p_id);
        $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
        $objectManager   = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $categories=array();
        if(count($cats) ){
            foreach($cats as $cat){
                $category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($cat);
                $categories[]=$category->getName();
            }

}
$item[$fieldName]=implode(',',$categories);
    }
}
return $dataSource;
```

Got Categories list in product grid. I have tried the following code for add filter,

```
<item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
```

and for add options to category filter dropdown,

```
<item name="options" xsi:type="object">Chilly\Productsgrid\Model\Category\Categorylist</item>
```

category dropdown came in filter section. But not add categories list to category dropdown. Have any idea, How to add category filter on product grid in magento2?

Comment: Ever find the answer to this I need it too :(

Comment: https://chillydraji.wordpress.com/2016/11/29/add-category-filter-to-product-grid-in-magento2/  - Check this link

Answer (score 0):

By default Magento2 not include js for dropdown.So override and use `product_listing.xml` in your module and add your column class for category options.( for format : see status)

Path:

```
<vendor>/<module>view/adminhtml/ui_component/product/product_listing.xml
```

and use below code :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
  <listingToolbar name="listing_top">     
    <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
    </filters>
</listingToolbar>
    <columns name="product_columns" class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="category_ids" class="<VENDOR><MODULE_NAME>\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Category">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="options" xsi:type="object"><VENDOR><MODULE_NAME>\Model\Category\Categorylist</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Categories</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
     </columns>
</listing>
```